# Using Microsoft Graph Search API in SPFx Web-Part?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

I am trying to prototype the use of Microsoft's new MS Graph Search APIs in a SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Web-Part in SharePoint.

While configuring the web-part, I've updated the package-solution.json file to include the needed **webApiPermissionRequests** (see below screenshot):

[image]

However, after deploying the app to the SharePoint app catalog and attempting to authorize the web-part's permissions via **SPO Admin Center > Advanced > API access**, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Is this not yet supported?

Here's the error I see when performing the same approval via PowerShell:
[image]

FYI — I tried to use the **microsoft-search** tag as recommended by MS here at stack overflow, but it does not yet exist and I don't have the reputation here to add it.

Comment: Based on the displayed error message, it would appear that your account does not have Tenant Admin privileges to be able to approve requests.  If you are already a Tenant Admin, then I suggest opening a support request with Microsoft.

Comment: The MS Graph search APIs are in private preview right now, so a support request won't get very far. Stack Overflow was their recommendation for questions so I'm hoping some of the MS dev team is listening. :)

Comment: The search APIs are in preview, but the Graph API permission requests and approvals are fully supported GA features.

Comment: Have you looked at the samples as https://github.com/microsoft-search/office-spfx-samples? I'm reworking them a bit, but those should work.